# Strange For-loop behavior

Tags: android, if-statement, for-loop

I'm seeing strange behavior in a for loop that contains an if-else if-else block.

If I do the following, it works as expected, except for the names that don't exist in my list:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
        String[] debtnameslist = res.getStringArray(R.array.debtnames);

        for(int i=1; i < debtnameslist.length; i++){
               if (debtname.toLowerCase().contains(debtnameslist[i]))
                   {
                   int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_dialog_"+debtnameslist[i], "drawable", "com.freshsoft.android.debtdestroyer");
                   icon.setImageResource(resID);
                   }
               else if ((debtname.toLowerCase().contains("best") && (debtname.toLowerCase().contains("buy"))))
               {
                   icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_dialog_bestbuy);
                }
//                 else {
//                     icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_dialog_dollar);
//                 }
          }
```

gives me this:
http://i54.tinypic.com/rsr33q.png

it works, except for the "test" that should show a generic symbol.  If I un-comment the //else portion, I get the following:

http://i54.tinypic.com/25kj6z6.png

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="debtnames">
    <item >chase</item>
    <item >discover</item>
    <item >citibank</item>
    <item >amazon</item>
    <item >american express</item>
    <item >diners</item>
    <item >mastercard</item>
    <item >visa</item>
    <item >paypal</item>
    <item >macys</item>
    <item >bmw</item>
    <item >target</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: i should start from 0...

Comment: i had tried that as well, but it didn't make a difference..still shows no icons except "target" for some reason  for what its worth here is my xml of names:
    <string-array name="debtnames">
        <item >chase</item>
        <item >discover</item>
        <item >citibank</item>
        <item >amazon</item>
        <item >american express</item>
        <item >diners</item>
        <item >mastercard</item>
        <item >visa</item>
        <item >paypal</item>
        <item >macys</item>
        <item >bmw</item>
        <item >target</item>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - if `debtnameslist[i]` does not contain any of the names in `debtnames` nor "best buy", It will put the dollar icon - because the first `if` is false, the second is false too.

You can't put a non conditional `else` clauses in there, because it will override the icon in the next loop!

And as you can see, the only 1 that works in this case is "target" - because it is last, theres no next loop to override its icon.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Is there a different way to test this?   I've currently got around 36 lines of if..elseif...elseif...etc lines and that is going to be a pain in the ass to maintain versus an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after screwing around with it for a while.  The trick was to break the loop if a match was found:

```
for (String name : debtnameslist) {
            boolean matches = debtname.toLowerCase().contains(name);
            if (matches)
            {
                int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_dialog_"+name, "drawable", "com.freshsoft.android.debtdestroyer");
                   icon.setImageResource(resID);
                  break;
            } else {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_dialog_dollar);
            }
        }
```